# Copy to the clipboard when running R online

Tags: r, clipboard, copy-paste

If I'm running R code using https://rdrr.io/snippets/, is it possible to use the `write_clip()` function? When I run `clipr_available()` in the window, it returns `FALSE`, which is probably not a good sign - is there anything (short of running R locally) that I can do to get this (or another method of copying to the clipboard) to work?

Comment: I don't think it is possible, `library(clipr); clipr::write_clip("some text", allow_non_interactive = TRUE)` this gives error, too, even though the clipr library is available.

Comment: do you run with linux mac or windows? I think there is no easy solution, if you use `read.DIF("clipboard")` you get `unable to contact X11 display`. This is normaly the display service for using your clipboard. In Ubuntu you pipe this one to xclip. Since you are using this on a server it should not be possible to contact local environment variables easily

Comment: I'm running macOS but the idea was to be able to give colleagues who are unfamiliar with R a simple script that they are able to run and easily get the output without having to download R and an IDE etc and use unfamiliar software, so ultimately I'd want it to work in whatever OS they use (probably Windows) with whatever browser they're using.